# How to parse FractalTransformer with normalizr

Tags: javascript, normalizr

I'm trying to use paularmstrong/normalizr on JSON that comes from FractalTransformer and whose nested childs have "data" attribute. Example of JSON:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "object": "Offer",
    "id": "5g6aqocew4qjzl40",
    "real_id": 26,
    "name": "Random Name",
    "created_at": {
      "date": "2019-06-18 11:13:08.000000",
      "timezone_type": 3,
      "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    "readable_created_at": "1 year ago",
    "site": {
      "data": {
        "object": "Site",
        "id": "65zody8vj29vlegd",
        "name": "Test Site",
        "real_id": 1
      }
    },
    "countries": {
      "data": [
        {
          "object": "Country",
          "code": "US",
          "name": "United States"
        },
        {
          "object": "Country",
          "code": "DE",
          "name": "Germany"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "meta": {
    "include": [
      "site",
      "countries"
    ],
    "custom": []
  }
}
```

Schemas I use:

```js
export const offerSchema = new schema.Entity('offers')
export const siteSchema = new schema.Entity('sites', {}, {
  processStrategy: (value) => {
      return { ...value.data }
  },
  idAttribute: (value) => {
      return value.data.id
  },
})
export const countrySchema = new schema.Entity('countries')

offerSchema.define({
  site: siteSchema,
  countries: [countrySchema],
})
```

Now the issue is that I remove 'data' from the site since it's just one object successfully, but I can't do it in the country case. Whatever I tried with custom processStrategy fails, as country is object that has data which is array (I assume this is where the issue is, going from Entity to Array). And in idAttribute function I always get complete array so can't determine the ID of single entry. So the end result is that the ID of countries is undefined. Any ides?

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed with another approach. I added processStrategy on the parent, 'Offer' in this case, so all 'data' parts get stripped before they reach other child schemas.

```js
const normalizrStripDataOptions = {
  processStrategy: (value) => {
    const ret = { ...value }

    Object.keys(ret).forEach((key) => {
      if (ret[key] !== null) {
        if (ret[key].data && Array.isArray(ret[key].data)) {
          ret[key] = [...ret[key].data]
        }

        if (ret[key].data && typeof ret[key].data === 'object') {
          ret[key] = { ...ret[key].data }
        }
      }
    })

    return ret
  },
}

export const offerSchema = new schema.Entity('offers', {}, normalizrStripDataOptions)
export const siteSchema = new schema.Entity('sites')
export const countrySchema = new schema.Entity('countries')

offerSchema.define({
  site: siteSchema,
  countries: [countrySchema],
})
```